# PHPlot with mySQL not updating wit new entries

Tags: php, mysql, graph, charts, graphing

I have a question, it may be stupid, I just started using this. I have a database with 5 entries, and I plotted a graph with PHPlot, and it won't update when I add a new entry. I have it set to show the last 5 entries in a line graph, but it's only showing 3 (there were 3 when I coded the script). Any help is appreciated. Here is the code.

```
<?php

//database connection
$dbname="localhost";
$dbun="username";
$dbpw="password";
$database="medtrack";

//my table1
$table="members";

// Connect to database
$conn = mysql_connect("$dbname", "$dbun", "$dbpw") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("$database", $conn) or die(mysql_error());


// Include files
include 'phplot/phplot.php';


// start array
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 36_mood ORDER BY 'id' DESC"); 
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) 
$data[$i] = mysql_fetch_array($qry); 


//array 1, id I didn't change the name yet, sorry
$date1=$data[0]['id'];
$date2=$data[1]['id'];
$date3=$data[2]['id'];
$date4=$data[3]['id'];
$date5=$data[4]['id'];

//array 2, moods - these are on a scale of 0-10, stored as int in the database
$mood1=$data[0]['mood'];
$mood2=$data[1]['mood'];
$mood3=$data[2]['mood'];
$mood4=$data[3]['mood'];
$mood4=$data[4]['mood'];


//Define the object
$plot2 = new PHPlot();

//Define some data
$example_data = array(
     array(1,$mood1),
     array(2,$mood2),
     array(3,$mood3),
     array(4,$mood4),
     array(5,$mood5),
);

$plot2->SetDataValues($example_data);

//Turn off X axis ticks and labels because they get in the way:
$plot2->SetXTickLabelPos('none');
$plot2->SetXTickPos('none');

//Draw it
$plot2->DrawGraph();

?>
```

All help is appreciated. I'm thinking if this doesn't work, to generate a page on the fly everytime the person clicks the graphs page. Any thoughts? I've tried libchart, but it doesn't like MySQL, I might try it again. I suck with Javascript. Thanks a LOT. All and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this a legacy application? `mysql_query` should not be used in new code.

Comment: I'll take care of all that later, right now its bare bones in testing phase. Thanks!

Comment: You should be using, at the absolute bare minimum, [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). The risk of making a mistake with `mysql_query` is way too high, and it's very easy to make those sorts of mistakes. Prototyping in a completely obsolete interface is wasting your time since you'll have to re-write everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your for-loop can only handle 3 entries.
you can use `mysql_num_rows($qry)`:

```
$rows = mysql_num_rows($qry); 
for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++)
    $data[$i] = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
```

Comment: Oh my, what a dumbbutt mistake. Duh! THANK YOU